# Socket.io not responding to events when used with React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm trying to connect my CRA front-end to my Socket.io websocket server made in Node.js, but it seems to not work. Here's the configuration of the Socket server:

```js
const app = require("express")();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

io.on("connection", function (socket) {
  console.log("A user connected.");

  socket.on("set video", function (url) {
    console.info("> Set the video to '" + url + "'");
    socket.broadcast.emit("set video", { url });
  });
});

server.listen(3001, function () {
  console.info("WS is listening on port 3001.");
});
```

And here's the React component:

```
type Props = {
  readonly method: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
};

const VideoProvider = () => {
  const [source, setSource] = useState<string>("");

  const handleSubmit = (event: FormEvent) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const ws = io("http://127.0.0.1:3001");
    ws.on("connect", function () {
      ws.emit("set video", { url: source });
    });
  };

  const handleChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setSource(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <fieldset style={{ width: "400px" }}>
      <legend>Set video URL</legend>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label htmlFor="video">Enter video's URL</label>{" "}
        <input
          id="video"
          type="url"
          placeholder="Enter video's URL (.mp4)"
          value={source}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />{" "}
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    </fieldset>
  );
};
```

When running the Socket server it returns callback of listen function, but nothing more:

```
Server is listening on port 3001.
```

How can I make it running?

Answer (score 0):

just migrated into websockets, these are not making any complains